# Expressing a function and differentiating.

Tags: derivatives

Show that $$ 1+\cot^2x=\text{cosec}^2x $$ where $0<x<\frac{π}{2}$. By expressing $ y=\cot^{-1}x$ as $x=\cot y,$ obtain $dy/dx$ in term of $x.$

Comment: Also how do you type this entire question in one line, i.e., no paragraphs every time i enter a expression.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\displaystyle y=\cot^{-1}(x)$

$\displaystyle x = \cot y\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dy} = -\csc^2 y = -(1+\cot^2 y) = -(1+x^2)$

So $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dy} = -(1+x^2)\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}$

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, we have

$$\begin{align}
1+\cot^2x&=1+\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x}\\\\
&=\frac{\sin^2 x+\cos ^2 x}{\sin^2 x}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\\\\
&=\csc^2x
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown.

Part 2:

We are given $y=\text{arccot} x \implies x=\cot y$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\frac{d\cot y}{dy}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{-\csc^2 y}\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{1+\cot^2y}\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{1+x^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.   I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, we know that $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x = 1$

Divide through by $\sin^2 x$:

$$1 + \frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x} = \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$$

$$ 1 + \cot^2 x= \text{cosec}^2 x$$

Alternatively, if you can't use the result:$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, you can just show that RHS = LHS (I would start with LHS)

$$x = \cot y \ \implies \frac{dx}{dy} = -\text{cosec}^2x= -(1+\cot^2 x)$$

Hence,

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{(1+\cot^2 x)}= -\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$